# Is there any procedure for solving this type of problems in $\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-numbers

We have
$$(1+i)^5=-4-4i$$ $$(1+i)^7=8-8i$$ $$(1+i)^9=16+16i$$

Now, considering that we have only this three complex numbers $-4-4i, 8-8i,  16+16i$ and we know that there is a complex number $c+id$ which can be represented as $(-4-4i)^x=(8-8i)^y=(16+16i)^z=c+id$ (here for $c=1$, $d=1$, $x=\frac15$, $y=\frac17$ and $z=\frac19$) but is it possible to find $c$,$d$,$x$,$y$ and $z$ values if we only know that $c$,$d$ values definitely exist and $x$,$y$,$z$ values are real.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The square root of $1+i$ can also be used to define $c$ and $d$, then $x$, $y$ and $z$ will just be half the suggested values. I.e. there is not a unique solution, so what do you really want?

Comment: Thank you, now I got your point but if there are three random complex numbers can we obtain a complex number that can be represented as a real powers of that three complex numbers. If there are infinitely many such complex numbers can we predict one. If so can you please explain me how?

Comment: In most cases I guess it's possible to find a common power, but it's easy to find complex numbers that doesn't have a common power. You basically just need to understand how multiplication (and thus exponentiation) of complex numbers work. The real powers of any complex number can't cross the unit circle (and only reach it if the number was on it), so just choose your three complex number with one inside, one on and one outside the unit circle, then they won't have real powers in common.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k = (1 + \mathbf{i})^9$

Hence, you have $k^z = k^{\frac{7y}{9}} = k^{\frac{5x}{9}}$. Your solutions are infinite but satisfy the conditions $[{x,y,z: z = \frac{7y}{9}, z = \frac{5x}{9}}]$. Essentially its a line of solutions:

[image: Function of solutions]

As for $c$ and $d$, expand the complex number and their powers using their polar forms and [De Movire's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) theorem, and you should get some relations between $c, d$ and $x,y,z$, such as $Re(c+d\mathbf{i}) = c = r_1^x\cos(x\theta) + r_2^y\cos(y\phi) + r_3^z\cos(z\gamma)$. This way you can "predict" $c,d$.